# Nativescript-vue buttons with image and tap response (tap-down event)

Tags: android, css, nativescript-vue

I just started playing with Nativescript-vue on [play.nativescript.org](http://play.nativescript.org).
Now I'd like to create big buttons with images on it that slightly change color when you tap (tap down).

Normal buttons already slightly change color when you tap (tested on android). But normal buttons with images don't and layout elements with images also don't.

The playground example is here: [my code on play.nativescript](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=37ItAW&v=14) (I pasted the code below as well).
In this basic app, the lower two buttons (without image) change color when tapped, but the top two buttons (with image) don't.

How do I add some animation/feedback to the buttons with the images?

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="*, *">
            <GridLayout @tap="onButtonTap" row="0" col="0" columns="*" rows="*" backgroundColor="#43b883">
                <Image row="0" col="0" src="https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/NativeScript_logo.png" />
            </GridLayout>
            <Button text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" row="0" col="1" backgroundImage="https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/NativeScript_logo.png"
         backgroundColor="#1c6b48" />
            <Button text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" row="1" col="0" backgroundColor="#289062" />
            <Button text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" row="1" col="1" backgroundColor="#43b883" />
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            onButtonTap() {
                console.log("Button was pressed");
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {};
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
    .home-panel {
        vertical-align: center;
        font-size: 20;
        margin: 15;
    }

    .description-label {
        margin-bottom: 15;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that a good way to style buttons with images and a different style when tapped is by adding some CSS. 
The `:highlighted` pseudo class is active when your finger is on the element and not when you release the button.

I ended up with [this code](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=37ItAW&v=29):

```
<template>
    <Page class="page">
        <ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar" />
        <GridLayout columns="*, *" rows="*, *">
            <Button class="button-1" text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" row="0" col="0" />
            <Button class="button-2" text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" row="0" col="1" />
            <Button class="button-3" text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" row="1" col="0" />
            <Button class="button-4" text="Button" @tap="onButtonTap" row="1" col="1" />
        </GridLayout>
    </Page>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            onButtonTap() {
                console.log("Button was pressed");
            }
        },

        data() {
            return {};
        }
    };
</script>

<style scoped>
    .home-panel {
        vertical-align: center;
        font-size: 20;
        margin: 15;
    }

    .description-label {
        margin-bottom: 15;
    }

    .button-1 {
        background-color: #43b883;
    }

    .button-2 {
        background-color: #1c6b48;
    }

    .button-3 {
        background-color: #289062;
    }

    .button-4 {
        background-color: #43b883;
    }

    button {
        background-image: url("https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/NativeScript_logo.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }

    button:highlighted {
        background-color: #000000;
    }
</style>
```